# Acessar rapidamente instância exata de elemento dentro de List java

Tags: java, lista, recursão, map

Tenho uma lista que vai ser abastecida com muitos pontos (x, y, z) - cerca de 3000. Cada ponto é único dentro da lista (sem pontos repetidos).

Em determinado momento o meu programa precisa recuperar a instância de um ponto armazenado na lista, pois cada ponto tem propriedades como "visitado", etc..

Existe algum meio de recuperar um certo ponto (a instância exata) de forma mais rápida, do que percorrendo a lista sequencialmente? A minha tentativa foi usar um Map que armazena o valor do ponto como P(x, y, z) e a instância do ponto. Só que isso não funcionou (dá erro de StackOverflow) - pois preciso acessar o ponto dentro de uma função recursiva.

```
for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < dimension; z++) {
                Point p = new Point(x, y, z);
                if (indexesBlocked.contains(i)) {
                    p.setBlocked(true);
                }
                points.add(p);
                map.put(p.getKey(), p);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Alguma ideia? Obrigado

Comment: Você pode colocar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Os pontos ficam armazenados em um `List<>` ou em um `Map<>` ou ambos? Pelo que eu sei o Map já vaz um _binary-search_ que é uma busca muito rápida, mas deve ser possível fazer o mesmo com `List<>` ([seria isto?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-)). Ainda há a possibilidade de fazer uma busca paralela (talvez com [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--)?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua solução atende o necessário, porém ela não irá obter performance satisfatória quanto mais sua lista de elementos crescer.

Algumas estruturas nos fornecem algoritmos (lembre-se de que estruturas não possuem complexidade, os algoritmos possuem :) ) que possuem tempo de busca padrões, eu recomendo você dar uma olhada [neste site](https://cooervo.github.io/Algorithms-DataStructures-BigONotation/index.html) de onde irei tirar algumas informações para a resposta.

Vamos dar uma olhada nas complexidades (notação Big O) existentes:

[image: Big O Board]

Podemos ver a relação entre **tempo (t)**  e **quantidade de elementos (n)** no quadro acima.

Atualmente seu acesso aos elementos sendo sequencial, a complexidade seria de *O(n)*, sendo que você pode ter a sorte de achar o item no começo da procura ou não, de qualquer forma o tempo cresce de acordo com o tamanho da sua coleção.

A estrutura recomendada para esta procura seria uma [tabela de dispersão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o), vulgo [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) e [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) no Java.

A idéia é que a chave do elemento seja o índice de acesso certeiro ao objeto que você procura, no seu caso a chave seria os pontos (x, y, z), para acessar a informação contida no valor do bucket:

```
public class Point {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int z;

    public Point(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                    .append(x)
                    .append(y)
                    .append(z)
                    .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        result = prime * result + z;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        if (z != other.z)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Para o teste de acesso podemos criar a seguinte massa:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Point, String> pointMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
                    Point point = new Point(x, y, z);
                    pointMap.put(point, point.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(pointMap.get(new Point(54, 99, 45)));
        System.out.println(pointMap.get(new Point(65, 99, 45)));
        System.out.println(pointMap.get(new Point(65, 1, 46)));
        System.out.println(pointMap.get(new Point(2, 99, 45)));
        System.out.println(pointMap.get(new Point(99, 99, 99)));

        long tempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(tempoFinal - tempoInicial);
    }

}
```

Estou representando 100 elementos x, 100 elementos y e 100 elementos z, totalizando 1.000.000 de elementos.

Ao executar o código você verá que os tempos de acesso são iguais tanto para o primeiro elemento quanto para o último elemento, desta forma então estamos acessando os elementos em *O(1)*.

É importante lembrar que o método `get` do HashMap utiliza o método `containsKey` para recuperar o valor da chave através da operação `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, dessa forma o `equals` da classe `Point` foi sobrescrito.